# Does anybody know how I'd create a column with more than one section inside it?

Tags: html-email, mjml

[image: Two column layout with multiple containers on left hand side]

Does anybody know how I'd recreate the picture here with mjml?

I can create two columns without any issues. My problem is creating that mustard yellow container for all the mj-text tags to go into.

Is there some kind of mj-div that I can use where I can then apply styles etc?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to MJML documentation:

> *`mj-text` is an "ending tag", which means it can contain HTML code*
> *which will be left as it is, so it can contain HTML tags with*
> *attributes, but it cannot contain other MJML components.*

[Source](https://documentation.mjml.io/#mj-text)

Which means you should be able to add HTML inside mj-text. Your resulting MJML will look something similar to:

```
<mjml>
  <mj-body>

    <!-- Side image -->
    <mj-section background-color="white">
      <!-- left paragraph -->
      <mj-column>
        <mj-text>
          <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>row 1</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>row 2</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>

        </mj-text>


      </mj-column>
      <!-- right image -->
      <mj-column>
        <mj-image width="200px" src="https://designspell.files.wordpress.com/2012/01/sciolino-paris-bw.jpg" />
      </mj-column>
    </mj-section>

  </mj-body>
</mjml>
```